# java 8 java.util.function.Function downcast

Tags: java-8

The below java function is assignable (f(Order) to f(Object))

```
    Function<Order, Order> orderProcessor = (Order order) -> {
        System.out.println("Processing Order:" 
        return order;
    };
```

***Function f = orderProcessor;***

The question is how do i cast this function back to Function < Order,Order> ?

or better I would like to cast this function back to Function < SomeInterface,SomeInterface>

I am storing these functions in a List< Function> but ideally i would like to store them in a List < SomeInterface,SomeInterface>. 
Is it possible ?

Comment: uhm ... no casting needed - this Function already has your mentioned signature. Are you confused because of the lambda notation?

Comment: why did you want to cast a `Function` to another `Function`? is there relationship between `Order` and `SomeInterface`?

Comment: For routing.  Based on a runtime field, the message can be routed dynamically to the correct handler(a function).

Comment: has your `Order` implemented `SomeInterface`?

Comment: Yes Order has implemented SomeInterface

Comment: When you assign, `Function<Order, Order>` to `Function`, you are assigning it to the *raw type* `Function`, not `Function<Object…>` or whatsoever. You are eliminating the type information and no, it won’t come back.

Comment: yet again : **no casting needed**, it doesnt even make any sense to cast `Function<Order, Order>` to `Function<Order, Order>`

Comment: …and what is `List < SomeInterface,SomeInterface>`?!

Comment: a `Function<Order, Order>` is not _castable_ to `Function<SomeInterface, SomeInterface>`, simply because it cannot accept implementations of `SomeInterface` that are not `Order` as parameter. You could cast it (even implicitly) to `Function<Order, ? extends SomeInterface>` if desired though (assuming the `Order` implements that interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a `List` takes `Function`s with 2 generic parameters `? extends SomeInterface`. then no need casting at all, for example:

```
List<Function<? extends SomeInterface, ? extends SomeInterface>> functions =
                                                                 new ArrayList<>();

Function<Order, Order> orderProcessor = (Order order) -> {
    System.out.println("Processing Order:" + order);
    return order;
};

functions.add(orderProcessor);
```

**IF** the result type is same as parameter type, you also can using a [UnaryOperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html) instead, for example:

```
List<UnaryOperator<? extends SomeInterface>> functions = new ArrayList<>();

UnaryOperator<Order> orderProcessor = (Order order) -> {
    System.out.println("Processing Order:" + order);
    return order;
};

functions.add(orderProcessor);
```

**THEN** you can't accept any `SomeInterface` at all, since the `Function<? extends SomeInterface>` can take any other subtypes not only for the `Order` class.

**IF** you want your `Function`s can accept all of its subtypes, you must declare it as write mode `? super SomeInterface`, and then you must change the `UnaryOperator<Order>` definition, for example:

```
List<UnaryOperator<? super SomeInterface>> functions = new ArrayList<>();

UnaryOperator<SomeInterface> orderProcessor = (SomeInterface item) -> {
    if(item instanceof Order){
       System.out.println("Processing Order:" + order);
    }
    return item;
};

functions.add(orderProcessor);
```

here is a solution wrap a `Map` in `Processors` then you don't need any casting or `instanceof` statement in `UnaryOperator` body, for example:

```
Processors processors = new Processors();

UnaryOperator<Order> orderProcessor = (order) -> {
    // no need instanceof & casting expression here
    System.out.println("Processing Order:" + order);
    return order;
};

processors.add(Order.class, orderProcessor);


processors.listing(Order.class).forEach(it -> it.apply(new Order()));
```

---

```
class Processors {
    private final Map<Class<?>, List<UnaryOperator<?>>> registry = new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends SomeInterface> void add(Class<T> type,
                                              UnaryOperator<T> processor) {
        registry.computeIfAbsent(type, aClass -> new ArrayList<>()).add(processor);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends SomeInterface> 
    Stream<UnaryOperator<T>> listing(Class<T> type){
        return (Stream<UnaryOperator<T>>) lookup(type).stream();
    }

    private List<?> lookup(Class<?> type) {
        if (!SomeInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) 
            return Collections.emptyList();

        if (!registry.containsKey(type)) 
            return registry.get(type.getSuperclass());

        return registry.get(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no sense in having `? extends SomeInterface` for the input parameter of a `Function`. This makes the function unusable.

Comment: Beautiful. But for some reason i get a compiler error when i now try to call  f.apply(someInterface)

Comment: @user2894020 this is because `? extends SomeInterface` can accept any subclasses not only for `Order`. so the functions can't be sure you can take the `Order` safely. for example: another function `BinaryOperator<BackedOrder>` only support the `BackedOrder`.

Comment: @Holger,  whats the alternative ? I am just trying to save(in a list) and use/call functions "polymorphically" based on an interface. Is this possible at all ?

Comment: I think now we're reaching the crux of my question. Sorry couldnt explain it very well in the beginning.

Comment: @user2894020: you have to improve your question, telling more about what you actually want to do. With more actual code, if possible.

Comment: @holi-java, thanks for the answer. I think i'll need to use instanceof.  But its not too bad because the handler deals with it.

Comment: @user2894020 Not at all. but I want to tell you if you have many `operators` ,you should consider using a `Map` rather than a `List`. then you can force-casting the functions and execute faster, and no need casting in your functions.

Comment: I do have a map. SomeInterface gives type information.  private Map<  Class < ? >,Function < ? super SomeInterface,? extends SomeInterface>> handlerMap . What do you mean by force-casting ?

Comment: @AmitGK Hi, I'm not good at english, so I give an example in my edited answer.

Comment: @holi-java english doesnt matter. Thank you very much for the code. Your solution is brilliant.